# Use nested attributes for model without auto-incrementing ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, accepts-nested-attributes

I have the following models with their corresponding schema definitions:

```
class Cube < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :faces, inverse_of: :cube, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :faces
end

create_table "cubes", id: :uuid, default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end


##
# NOTE: Even though this model's related database table has an +id+ column, it
#       is not a regular auto-generated, auto-incremented ID, but rather an +id+
#       column that refers to an uuid that must be manually entered for each
#       Face that is created.
##
class Face < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cube, inverse_of: :faces, optional: true
  validates :id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end

# Note that id defaults to nil.
create_table "faces", id: :uuid, default: nil, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.uuid "cube_id"
  t.index ["cube_id"], name: "index_faces_on_cube_id"
end
```

As you can see from the comments above, `id` is not automatically generated for the `Face` model, but rather is expected to be entered when they are created (because we are modeling something that in the real world already has a unique identifier, which we want to use instead of adding another ID).

The **problem** comes when I try to do the following:

```
cube = Cube.new

cube.faces_attributes = [
  {
    id: "2bfc830b-fd42-43b9-a68e-b1d98e4c99e8"
  }
]

# Throws the following error
# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Face with ID=2bfc830b-fd42-43b9-a68e-b1d98e4c99e8 for Cube with ID=
```

which to me means that since we are passing an `id`, Rails expects this to be an update on an associated `Face`, instead of passing a new `Face` to be created and associated with the `cube`.

Is there a way for me to disable this default behavior by `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, or do I have to write custom code for my specific use case?

Comment: I think if you want to create a associated object in controller action, you must create it with a `new` keyword. Like - `face = Face.new` and `cube.face = face`, or something like that

Comment: @PlanB yeah, that looks like it could work. I was just asking "out of curiosity" to see if the "Convention over configuration" of nested attributes could be bent for this specific case. Thanks for contributing

Comment: I think you better stay with `Convention over configuration`. And keeping original record id, I think is not a broblem. You can have two ids for same object because original id starts from 0 (or 1), so its not `heavy` anyway. And most important - concentrate on serious issues (while this is isnt) :)

Comment: I mean, it looks like not a serious issue, because you dont loose any data

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the model to use a non-standard foreign key.

```
class Face < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = 'uuid'
  belongs_to :cube, inverse_of: :faces, optional: true
  # your validation is for the wrong column.
  validates :uuid, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

However in any decent database design primary keys are unique. Thats the whole point behind a unique identifier! Since NULL is not unique it must also be NOT NULL. This should be enforced on the DB level. Not just with a app level validation.

A better solution with far less headaches however might be to stick with the Rails convention of naming the foreign key `id` and changing its type to UUID instead of a auto-incrementing id. This will reduce the amount of configuration needed in each model considerably.